# Accessing JSF2 composite component attributes in backing component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I'm developing a JSF2/Primefaces app and I'm having trouble with accessing attributes defined in an interface of a composite component in this component's backing bean.

My component is defined as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface componentType="testComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="text" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <h:outputText value="Passed text is: #{cc.attrs.text}" />

</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

It is stored in a file called `text.xhtml` located in: `application/src/main/webapp/resources/my_component` directory.

I use this component on another page (which is a Facelets composition element) like so:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:myc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my_component"
    template="./resources/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content"> 
    <h:form id="products">
        <myc:test id="test" text="A text" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>    

</ui:composition>
```

The backing component class is defined as follows:

```
package my.application.component;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@FacesComponent ( value="testComponent" )
public class TestComponent extends UINamingContainer {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestComponent.class);

    public TestComponent() {
        log.debug("TestComponent constructor");
        log.debug("getAttributes().size(): " + getAttributes().size());
    }
}
```

The component itself works as expected. The using page renders `Passed text is: A text` output.
Also, logger output displays log messages from `TestComponent` constructor, so it seems that the component xml definition is correctly bound with the `TestComponent` class.

Now, the **problem** is that the `getAttributes()` method invoked in `TestComponent` constructor always returns a zero-sized map.
If I understand this correctly, I should be able to access the `text` attribute declared in component's interface using a call:

`getAttributes().get("text");`

in the `TestComponent` class, but it always returns `null` as the attributes map is empty.

I also tried to access the `text` attribute using a call:

`String text = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().
        evaluateExpressionGet(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "#{cc.attrs.text}", String.class));`

but it also resolves to `null`.

What am I doing wrong? Any tips will be much appreciated as I have no idea what to try next.

/Tukasz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the constructor is too early to reference those attributes.

JSF will construct an instance of the backing component first, and will then at some point give it a reference to its attributes. In a method that's called later, eg the encode method, you should have access to them.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks. I'll give it a try and check if the attributes are accessible in `encode` method.

Comment: Hi again. Yes. The attributes are accessible in the `encode[All|Begin|End|Childen](FacesContext context)` methods. Thank you very much for the help. 

But I still wonder if one of these methods is the right place to access the attributes if I want to use them in some way before my component is rendered. In a `@ManagedBean`s I use `@PostConstruct` methods for such purpose, but this doesn't seem to work in a `@FacesComponent` class.

Comment: Maybe someone should file a request for that? `@PostConstruct` in `@FacesComponent` would be great!